# Seaborn to a image object without saving it

Tags: python, image, seaborn

I have a seaborn figure, I want convert the figure to a bytes object.

With plotly I would do something like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()

fig = px.bar(wide_df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input, relabelled",
             labels={"value": "count", "variable": "medal"})

# Convert the figure to a bytes object
img_bytes = pio.to_image(fig, format='png')

# Pass the bytes object to the other function
other_function(img_bytes)
```

With seaborn, I'm using this function, but is being saved...

```
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix([0,1,1], [0,1,0])
ax = sns.heatmap(
        cf_matrix, annot=labels, fmt="", vmin=0, vmax=100
    )

sns_figure = ax.get_figure()

cm_image = sns_figure.savefig('test_image.png')
```

I've also tried with the following (with a plotly fig works) but not with seaborn

```
import plotly.io as pio
img_bytes = pio.to_image(fig_sns, format='png')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The fig parameter must be a dict or Figure. Received value of type <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>: Figure(640x480)
```

Comment: I don't use either, I was guessing. So, I'll remove that in order not to lead others astray. It seems the function you use already returns bytes, so try looking at the first few to see if it looks like a `PNG`. That is, `print(img_bytes[:20])`

Comment: `ax.get_Figure()` returns: `type <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>: Figure(640x480)` @MarkSetchell

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question can help you further, they use `savefig()` to save to an `io.BytesIO` buffer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564943/saving-matplotlib-plot-to-memory-and-placing-on-tkinter-canvas

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

I've did the following:

```
import io

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix([0,1,1], [0,1,0])
ax = sns.heatmap(
        cf_matrix, annot=labels, fmt="", vmin=0, vmax=100
    )

sns_figure = ax.get_figure()

buf = io.BytesIO()

sns_figure.savefig(buf, format='png')

buf.seek(0)
image = buf.read()

#Return image as an bytes object
return image
```